# Adding another class to an element, but as the first class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to add another class to a element, but some of those elements already have an existing class, however the class I am adding I want it to be the `first class` added in the class field and don't want to append it; because from what I know, in general, rules in the last listed class will overwrite rules in the former classes, correct!?

I know of a jquery method as below..

```
$("p").addClass("myClass");
```

However from what I understand this just appends the class and you can't choose where to put it.

Is there any way to do this easily or will I have to start removing classes and re-adding them?

Comment: simply change the specificity of your rule instead of hacking sth here in? (by prepending an asterisk to your rule)

Comment: `rules in the last listed class will overwrite rules in the former classes` this is in the css declaration not in the class attribute.

Comment: First create some scenarios to test this out. Have a css with two styles, and then apply the same two classes to two divs in different order. After that rearrange the declarations in the css file, and rerun the test. In my opinion the order of the declarations count only (later declared/included wins)

Comment: you could use `insertBefore()` or `before()` couldn't you (if you wanted to insert the new class before the current one)?

Comment: `insertBefore()` and `before()` are used to add new elements, right? Or am I falling short on info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is any need to do something like this, I personally like advice of @bwoebi just change specifity.

But still if you need it, this might help

**HTML**

```
<div class="second">Lorem text</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var $div = $('div'),
    classes = $div.attr('class');
$div.attr('class', 'first' + ' ' + classes);
```

You can put your variable which contains class's name in place of `'first'`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/knznv/)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun in case you wanted to add the new class at a specific index inside the current classes:

http://jsfiddle.net/ckzVk/

```
function addClassAtIndex(elementId,classNameToAdd,index){
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var elementClasses = element.className.split(" ");
    elementClasses.splice(index,0,classNameToAdd);
    var newClasses = elementClasses.join(" ");
    element.className = newClasses;
}
```

To add class "man" to div:

```
<div id="stuff" class="cool bro sweet">The div.</div>
```

JS:

```
addClassAtIndex("stuff","man",1");
```

Result:

```
<div id="stuff" class="cool man bro sweet">The div.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You add multiple classes to an element by simply separating the classes using a space. For example:

```
<p class="key_paragraph dark no_border">Your text here</p>
<p class="key_paragraph dark">Your text here</p>
```

**The order in which the classes are listed in the html attribute does not matter. What matters is the stylesheet.**

In your stylesheet (css file), if you want any of the classes to override another you could change the order of the rules in the stylesheet. For example, if the class 'dark' has a border and the class 'no_border' does not, you must place 'no_border' after 'dark' in your stylesheet to ensure 'no_border' overrides 'dark' for the first paragraph. Like so:

```
.dark {
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.no_border {
    border: none;
}
```

Secondly, you could add specificity regardless of the order of the css rules. For example, combining classes to say 'if an element has the classes dark and red' is more specific than either of the two above rules. See [here](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) for more info on specificity. Thus, the following rule would ensure there is no border on elements with the classes 'dark' and 'no_border' regardless of the order in which they appear on the stlesheet:

```
.dark.no_border {
    border: none;
}

.dark {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

A third option is to use the css :not selector to target all elements with the class 'dark' that do not also have the class 'no_border'. Again, the order of rules in the stylesheet will not matter here. This is done as follows:

```
.no_border {
    border: none;
}

.dark:not(.no_border) {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

There are other ways to do this, but hopefully I have explained three easy ways in a manner you can understand. There is a more jquery-specific demo [here](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) (see the third example). Let me know if you have any questions.